# Unable to print the output using selenium java for https://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/register_sucess.php

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Need help with printing the output from https://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/register_sucess.php uisng selenium java
Once you submit the registration form you are presented with its details as attached.
I tried multiple ways to interact using absolute xpath, relative xpath etc but unable to get the text in console. My locators are as below. Could anyone of you please help.

@FindBy(xpath = "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td/p[1]/font/b")
WebElement p1;

```
@FindBy(xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/p[2]")
WebElement p2;

@FindBy(xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/p[3]/font/b")
WebElement p3;

public void getParaText() {
    p1.getText();
    p2.getText();
    p3.getText();
    System.out.println(p1);
    System.out.println(p2);
    System.out.println(p3);
}
```

I tried most of the locating strategies to get the text from attribute and get its value, but nothing worked